# How to see object from new THREE.BufferGeometryLoader() globally

Tags: three.js

I have to make rotation for my Mesh in render. For this I have to see my mesh globally. I create Mesh form object loader (json). So, I it just inside call back function. And when I try to create var with object before the function and then to give value of function it doesn't work.
How I can make my Mesh globally?

```js
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: earthTexture });
   let objectLoader = new THREE.BufferGeometryLoader();
   objectLoader.load('geometry.json',
    function (geometry) {
     
     var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(object);
});
```

Comment: What is `fontsObject` in your code?

Comment: I changed it on object. I also use fonts from json, but is doesn't matter now

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable and assign its value in the callback function, then just check if the variable is not undefined:

```
var obj; // define this variable in the section - let camera, scene, renderer;

. . .

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: earthTexture });
    let objectLoader = new THREE.BufferGeometryLoader();
    objectLoader.load('geometry.json',
        function (geometry) {

        var obj = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        scene.add(obj);
});

...
// somewhere in your animation loop
if (obj) obj.rotation.y += 0.1;
```

Comment: obj is undefined. It doesn't work in Three js. Things from loader I dont see outside of call back function, event if var is declared before

Comment: @Natalia Is there any chance to provide a working live code example or the link to your project?

Comment: https://github.com/NataliaGon/ThreeJS there is link on my Git Hub. It is great if you can have look

Answer (score 0):

I served it , I created var objectWrapper = new THREE.Object3D(); in which i put my Object

Comment: Loading is an asynchronous operation, that's why it's better to load all resources and then run an animation loop.